# problem with keypress (in jquery) with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

problem with keypress (in jquery) with IE

```
$(document).keypress(function(key) {
    if (key.which == 99 && key.metaKey == true) {
        alert("Don't Copy");
        return false;
    }
});
```

It doesn't work !

How can I fix it ?

Comment: are you alerting something , you haven't written any code for checking keys ?

Comment: The code you have there prevents the key press from happening (`return false;`)...is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Then still: what is this code supposed to do? Block which key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why keypress?

```
$('*').bind('copy',function(key) {
    alert("Don't Copy");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that there is a specific `copy` event (although it doesn't work in Opera). Much better than 6-10 lines of CSS/JavaScript. +1

Comment: Binding to $('*') is a bad idea, you'll be adding event handler to every single element. If 'copy' event bubbles up, it's enough to bind to 'body'.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to check the status of `ctrlKey` to block <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>:

```
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    if (key.which == 67 && key.ctrlKey) {
        alert("Don't Copy");    
        return false;           
    }                           
});
```

It does work on all major browsers (FF4b7, IE 8), but not entirely correct in Chrome 8: although the alert pops up, the copy-to-clipboard behaviour is not suppressed.

That said, if you want to prevent the user from copying your texts to the clipboard, I'll have to disappoint you: someone can simply use the (context) menu option or view your page's source. There's nothing that you can do about that.